# How to dump and download mysql from remote machine with php?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, ssh

It is simple to dump mysql database when to login vps machine.
1.To login in the vps machine from my local machine with

```
ssh   root@vps_ip
```

2.To dump the mysql database named wpdatabase into /home/test.sql in the remote machine.

```
mysqldump  -u root -p   wpdatabase > /home/test.sql
```

Now ,can I  dump and download mysql from remote machine with php,to write login statement with php,download the dumped mysql database with php,all the process done with php ?

think to Adrian Cid Almaguer,i want to run exec("ssh root@vps_ip"); but how to write password in exec command?

```
man ssh  

   ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
         [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option]
         [-p port] [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname
         [command]
```

Can't write password in ssh?

Comment: going to depend on the size of your database really. also, if thats a wordpress database, there are plugins that will do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
    $vps_ip= vps_ip;
    $connection = ssh2_connect($vps_ip, 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $root, $passwd);
    $cmd1="mysqldump -u root -pxyzzy wpdatabase > /home/back.sql";
    ssh2_scp_recv($connection, '/home/back.sql', '/home/back/myback.sql');
?>
```

~

It is the better way to do the job for me.

Answer (score 3):

To connect with ssh:

First install from your console `sshpass`

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Then you can use this command

```
$ sshpass -p your_password ssh user@hostname
```

With php is

```
<?php

 exec("sshpass -p your_password ssh user@hostname");

?>
```

You can dump your database with:

```
<?php

 exec("mysqldump -uroot -padmin wpdatabase > /home/test.sql");

?>
```

> Note: `root` is he user and `admin` is the password.

Reference:

> https://serverfault.com/q/241588/283624

Comment: provided the database size doesn't cause `mysqldump` to exceed the `max_execution_time`

Comment: The php file was executed  after i login in my vps machine from local machlne ,and the  /home/test.sql is in the vps machine .

Comment: 1. to execute the php file on my local machine

Comment: 2. the test.sql file is on my local machine after  executed the php file.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature you got some advance?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two commands in Bash:

1) Using SSH, generate the MySQL dump (the missing space between -p and the database password is intentional):

```
$ ssh user@mysqlhost -x "mysqldump -u dbuser -pdbpass db_name > ~/file.sql"
```

2) Using SCP, transfer the file to your local home directory:

```
$ scp user@mysql_host:~/file.sql ~/
```

Please take a look at this blog post for how to set up SSH keys on your server, so you do not have to enter your password: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: The OP wants to know how it's done with PHP, probably looking more along the lines of requiring ssh2 php-extension and will need to $ssh->exec('mysqldump........') etc